# Committing same file to different forks. Will this cause problems?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

In short, I am a designer on an engineering team that is working on multiple forks. I would like my team to always be using the latest iOS app icon, but I don't want to burden them by asking them to swap the art out every other day.

My first thought was that I should just clone all their forks, then commit the new artwork to each fork, but one of my co-workers thinks these identical files will cause a merge conflict when merging everything back in to main. Thoughts? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: If the file you commit to multiple forks is indeed identical, I don't think there will be a merge conflict (since the conflict requires a difference to exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do this would be to use a pull request for each of the forks. The commit that you are referencing will have a unique hash - the repository will know that it is the same commit in each fork.

https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests

Comment: Is there an equivalent to a "pull request" if you're not using github, or is this just a meta-function provided by them? (I realize the question is tagged github so your answer is relevant, I'm just wondering what the best way to do this would be when using a private ssh-attached repo.)

Comment: The pull request becomes, "Hey Floyd, can you pull from the repo?" :)

Comment: I've never done it, but according to http://git-scm.com/book/ch5-2.html: "When your work has been pushed up to your fork, you need to notify the maintainer. This is often called a pull request, and you can either generate it via the website — GitHub has a "pull request" button that automatically messages the maintainer — or run the `git request-pull` command and e-mail the output to the project maintainer manually."

Comment: @doublesharp Does this mean I need to commit to main, then do a pull request from each fork?

Comment: If you want it to be the "same" commit, then yes, however as other have pointed out as long as the binary is the same you won't have a merge conflict.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no merge conflict when merging identical files. If the files are not exactly identical, for example if they differ by even a single bit, only then there will be a merge conflict. Try it, you can easily test this in two local branches.